# Can I push to Bitbucket using Http instead of https?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I know this is a question that many of you will think that can be solved easily by pushing using https, but I cannot push over https.

I have a repository that I need pushed into Bitbucket, however, the way they allow to push is on https, which is obviously a good idea, but I cannot use https, so, does anybody knows if there is a way to push a repository into Bitbucket using http? I know that this has many security issues, but I have to deal with the fact that the ssl port is closed on the proxy I'm behind.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not - are you able to use SSH instead?

From the BitBucket documentation: "You can use either secure hypertext transport protocol (HTTPS) or secure shell (SSH) to connect to bitbucket."

Comment: Sadly SSH is even more difficult to use than ssl as it requires port 22

Comment: Sorry to hear that David, it may be more secure to copy source to a USB key and do a push via a location where the ports are enabled... although I shudder at the thought of keeping code on a USB drive, if the security is lax enough to not allow SSL or SSH it may be the best bet

Comment: Thanks for that Robert, however, you just gave me a nice idea and I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this, we encountered this issue today (proxy denied https).  We tried using http instead of https for Bitbucket, and it just worked.